# Orientability of $\mathbb{Z}^n$

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, infinite-combinatorics, directed-graphs

For any set $X$ set $[X]^2 = \{\{x,y\}: x,y\in X, x\neq y\}$. If $n\geq 2$ is an integer, we endow $\mathbb{Z}$ with a graph structure in the following way. If $x,y\in \mathbb{Z}^n$ we say $x,y$ are *direct neighbors* if there is $k\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$ such that $|x_k-y_k|= 1$, and $x_i = y_i$ for all $i\in \{1,\ldots,n\}\setminus\{k\}$. Let $$E_n= \big\{\{x,y\}\in [\mathbb{Z}^n]^2: x,y \text{ are direct neighbors}\}.$$

For which $n\geq 2$ is there an [orientation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orientation_(graph_theory)) of $(\mathbb{Z}^n, E_n)$ such that for every two vertices $x,y\in \mathbb{Z}^n$ there is a directed path from $x$ to $y$?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Color the vertices of $\mathbb{Z}^n$ by black and white according to their parity. For all but one "direction" (by direction I mean the direction of $x-y$), orient the edges from white to black. Orient the edges of the  remaining direction from black to white. Then, for any $x∈\mathbb{Z}^n$ with neighbour $y$, there is a directed path from $x$ to $y$ with length at most three. It follows that, for every two vertices $x,y∈\mathbb{Z}^n$ there is a directed path from $x$ to $y$.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a somewhat different solution phrased in a slightly more colorful language. For $\mathbb{Z}^2$, draw a spiral starting from $(0,0)$, i.e. edges $(0,0)$ to $(1,0)$, $(1,0)$ to $(1,1)$, $(1,1)$ to $(0,1)$ to $(-1,1)$, etc. Then it is possible to go from $(0,0)$ to any other point by following the spiral.

Now draw a chimney $(n+1,0)$ to $(n,0)$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then it is possible to go from any point to $(0,0)$ by following the spiral until it crosses the chimney and then dropping down the chimney. Hence all points in  $\mathbb{Z}^2$ are connected.

For $\mathbb{Z}^3$, connect all floors $\mathbb{Z}^2 \times k$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ as above and connect the floors by two elevators, one going up, the other one going down, i.e. draw edges $(0,0,k)$ to $(0,0,k+1)$ and $(0,1,k)$ to $(0,1,k-1)$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then $\mathbb{Z}^3$ is connected (go from the starting room to the elevator, change floors, go to the desired room).

The step from $\mathbb{Z}^n$ to $\mathbb{Z}^{n+1}$ is the same. 
(The remaining edges can be oriented randomly.)